# IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Branch.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Branch normal armv7

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, xcode10

I have used this CLI:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

I have tried a lot of workarounds. But none of them worked. Any help would be a great help here.

> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed: Ld
>   /Users/sampath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/You_are_a_CEO-gfwfhmbrnyncfrdrmuirefpabjjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/You\
>   are\ a\
>   CEO/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Branch.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Branch
>   normal armv7 Ld
>   /Users/sampath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/You_are_a_CEO-gfwfhmbrnyncfrdrmuirefpabjjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/You\
>   are\ a\
>   CEO/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Branch.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Branch
>   normal arm64 (2 failures)

**Ionic info:**

```
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.5.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.4
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 29 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.4
NodeJS : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 5.6.0
OS : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

*package.json*

```
    {
    "name": "ambassador",
    "version": "3.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "ios-deploy": "^1.9.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/branch-io": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.9.1",
        "@ionic-native/contacts": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^4.14.0",
        "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.12.2",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.14.0",
        "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/mixpanel": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/music-controls": "^4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.9.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "^1.0.20",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "@vimeo/player": "^2.6.3",
        "angular-progress-bar": "^1.0.3",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
        "angular2-google-place": "^2.0.2",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
        "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
        "branch-cordova-sdk": "^3.1.3",
        "com.synconset.imagepicker": "^2.1.10",
        "cordova-android": "6.4.0",
        "cordova-clipboard": "^1.2.1",
        "cordova-custom-config": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "^1.6.0",
        "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.10",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^2.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.0.19",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.4.6",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git#2.6.0",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": "^2.3.6",
        "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": "^4.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-music-controls": "^2.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.1.2",
        "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.3",
        "cordova-sms-plugin": "^0.1.13",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.5.2",
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.10",
        "css-animator": "^2.3.0",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
        "firebase": "4.8.2",
        "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
        "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.6.2-alpha",
        "ionic2-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.0.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "list": "1.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
        "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.4.5",
        "promise-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
        "pubnub": "^4.21.5",
        "pubnub-angular2": "^1.3.1",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
        "@ionic/lab": "1.0.11",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Upload profile pic",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Upload profile pic",
                "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library."
            },
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
                "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate your Location"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-contacts": {
                "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To invite Friends"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-music-controls": {},
            "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
            "cordova-clipboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "com.synconset.imagepicker": {
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library.",
                "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library."
            },
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "2178440625814934",
                "APP_NAME": "You Are a CEO",
                "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": {
                "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
                "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "xxxx",
                "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "xxxxx",
                "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+",
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location while this app runs only.",
                "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background."
            },
            "branch-cordova-sdk": {},
            "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
                "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "23+",
                "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
                "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
                "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
                "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
                "ACCOUNT_TYPE": "$PACKAGE_NAME.account",
                "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME",
                "ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app always requires location tracking"
            },
            "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
            "cordova-sms-plugin": {},
            "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
            },
            "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
            "cordova-custom-config": {}
        },
        "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
            "APP_ID": "xxxx",
            "CHANNEL_NAME": "Production",
            "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
            "MAX_STORE": "2"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Branch.io` team has fixed this issue on version `3.1.5`.

[Fix iOS dependency issue.](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/releases/tag/v3.1.5)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova does not support Xcode 10 at the moment. You will be able to make debug builds, but production builds and archiving a build aren't guaranteed. You will have to downgrade Xcode to version 9.x to archive until the next version of cordova ios is released with support for Xcode 10.

Steps to downgrade xcode :

- Download an older version of xcode from the [Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode)
- Unzip the content of the download Replace the xcode folder under
- Applications directory with the downloaded folder.

Cordova announcement: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

Comment: No. This is not right. They have mentioned the problem is due to a new build system on `Xcode 10`. But I have disabled it like so `ionic cordova build ios --prod -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`. We can't use `Xcode 9` since it doesn't support `iOS 12.1`. Your thoughts?

Comment: I agree, it isn't the ideal situation. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a workaround besides a downgrade.

Comment: Hope you cannot use your app with `iOS 12.1` no? Did you try that?

Comment: An app archived with xcode 9 and published to the app store works on iOS 12. For development, no it doesn't.